# Regression and sampling issues : risk of selection bias when estimating gender gap?

Tags: regression, sampling, bias

I have been told to estimate a gender and nationality gap using a regression model for a dataset provided by a third party.

The dataset contains information about workers in a very specific sector.

A sample of X companies was drawn from a population of companies operating in that specific sector. Then, data were collected on all workers employed in the selected companies (lot of informations are available).

There are large and small companies, so some large companies have many observations (rows in the dataset), while each small company has only 1 or a very few rows.

I am not sure if this is a good framework for a regression analysis. I think there is a non-negligible selection bias going on...

Do you agree with me? If not, why ?

I am very hesitant and not sure if I should really do this analysis...or, If further adjustments need to be made, such as the random deletion of some observations for larger companies to reduce their weight in the sample.

Thank you for your comments and suggestions :-)

Comment: What is (roughly) the specification you wish to estimate?